# ubuntu dual boot Instalation instructions

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am installing Ubuntu to a dual boot system I have 2 Hard drives one has two partitions the other has one. I want to install Ubuntu to one hard drive.

When I get to the partition screen and check the hard drive I want to use, I get a popup window telling me there needs to be a root file system  defined??

There are three small boxes below the drive selection area: `change> delete> Revert`

Now in a windows setup you delete, create a partition and then format w/ a file system then install the OS.

`Change` does open a new box to size the partition and other options but since I have never setup Ubuntu before I am not sure what the procedure is.

Does anyone have the time to step me through this setup?

Comment: Ubuntu should  have a root partition (labelled /) and a swap partition. Root partition is where the majority of disk is allocated, and you can accomplish this easily with gparted live. Use ext 4 filesystem.

Comment: What OS do you currently have? (Asking as an answer because can't comment)
The instructions for windows 8/8.1 are different then XP,Vista, and 7